# Is there support for "Full Keyboard Access" in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, accessibility

Is there a way to tell when a user navigates to let's say a button using an external keyboard ? i.e accessibility option **Full Keyboard Access** is enabled, and an external bluetooth keyboard is connected to the iOS device.

I'm facing an issue where the focus indicator is not clearly visible, so i want change the style (changing border colour/width) of the button when this happens.

I thought of using onFocus but it's not being called.

```
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={props.onPress}
      accessibilityLabel={props.accessibilityLabel}
      accessibilityRole="button"
      onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
    >
      <View
        style={
          isFocused
            ? styles.buttonPrimaryFocus
            : styles.buttonPrimary
        }
      >
          <Text>
            {props.label}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ReactNative doesn't provide default solution.
I hope this solution will be suitable for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-external-keyboard

```
      import {ExternalKeyboardView} from 'react-native-external-keyboard';
  <ExternalKeyboardView
    onKeyDownPress={(e) => console.log(e)}
    onKeyUpPress={(e) => console.log(e)}
    onFocusChange={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.isFocused)}
    canBeFocused
  >
```

It is compatible with new and old arch.